# A column has a mix between City and State AND just City. I've already separated City and State, but how do I keep the correct City fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

In my table, I have 2 columns that I need to fix. The first column is "City" and it contains a mix of both the City and the State and just the City. The second column is "State" and has a mix of Nulls and States. It's important to note that when the Ciy column contains both the City and the State, the "State" column is Null.

```
NEW YORK,NY | NULL
NEW YORK    | NY
```

So far, I have written code that separates the "City" Column; however, when the City column doesn't contain the state, it goes ' ' and then the state column gets filled with the "City" value. The second two columns below are "City_Split" and "State2".

```
NEW YORK,NY | NULL | NEW YORK | NY
NEW YORK    | NY   | ''       | NEW YORK
```

I've tried case statements thus far, but I'm just confused.

I want:

```
NEW YORK,NY | NULL | NEW YORK | NY
NEW YORK    | NY   | NEW YORK | NY
```

```
SELECT
    CITY, CPS,
    SUBSTRING(CITY, 0, CHARINDEX(',', CITY, - 1)) AS CITY_SPLIT,
    SUBSTRING(CITY, CHARINDEX(',', CITY) + 1, LEN(CITY)) AS STATE2
FROM srcFlatFile.dbo.SWIFT AS SWIFT
WHERE (ISO_COUNTRY_CODE = 'US')
```

I apologize if I didn't ask the question clearly enough, I'm new to coding in general.

Comment: `SUBSTRING(CITY, 1, CHARINDEX(',', CITY) - 1))`

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (<your query>)
update data set city = city_split, state = state2
where charindex(',', city) > 0
```

You need to have the extra condition that limits the update to rows that need updating. Because those expressions require that a comma is present.

That approach is a simple way to use the `select` as is. But it really could (and should?) Be done without the CTE this way:

```
update srcFlatFile.dbo.SWIFT
set city = substring(city, 1, charindex(',', city) - 1),
       state = substring(city, charindex(',', city) + 1, 2)
where charindex(',', city) > 0
```

Comment: The `where charindex(',', city) > 1` fixed my query! Thank you so much, sir!

Comment: @Lizzie Actually I guess I should have written `> 0`. Glad it worked!